# Identify: 26in dirt jumper/bmx bike "fetish" brand?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I bought a 26in dirt jumper/bmx bike. No markings but the guy said it was a fetish. The set up is bmx but the frame looks like a jumper. Bmx cranks and dropouts.  The serial number is SNFSD13BF1725.

Comment: Without a photo it's unlikely we'll be able to help. Can you upload a photo for us? [This site](http://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/fetish/) has some pics, and I used [this search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=fetish+26"+dirt+jumper+bike) to find that. If you click over to "images" on that google search there are more pictures of bikes that might match. If you find what you want from there please report back - you can edit your question or post an answer.

Comment: So your question is "did I buy a pig-in-a-poke" ?

Answer (score 2):

Fetish bikes are a white label brand out of Taiwan. Most of their bikes change year to year and rarely have any identifying markings to a model outside a sticker (which is not applied when shipped, leaving it optional for the first owner to apply).

Honestly it may not ever truly be identified. If you need a replacement part or repair, it's best to take it to a bike shop for the proper part analysis if you don't know what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Schwinn.  I used the first 5 digits of the serial and plugged it into this stolen bikes registry website.  There's a bike starting with a similar serial number also starting with SNFSD followed by the same number of characters:
http://bikeindex.org/bikes/3836

Does the picture look like yours?